# How do you get rid of file contents without the filename?

Tags: c, file-io

I have a function that takes in a file pointer (`FILE * file`) and copies everything in that file. Now, is it possible to erase everything inside this file?

I do not have the file name so I can not use `fopen(filename, "w")` again.

I have `stdio.h` and `string.h` included.

Comment: I don't agree with downvoting. It is an interesting matter.

Comment: `rewind(fp); fprintf(fp, "");`

Comment: @stackptr: The snippet you show would just write nothing  to the beginning of the file. Not a single byte got truncated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ftruncate()` system call to empty a file using its file descriptor, e.g.

```
ftruncate(fileno(fh), 0);
```

You will probably want to follow that up with a call to `rewind(fh)` so that any further writes to the file are made at the beginning, rather than at the previous offset.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `ftruncate()` is prototyped in `unistd.h`.

Comment: Just to make sure: it is impossible to to wipe a file without using unistd.h function.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's *some* way to do it using stdio, but if there is, it's much less obvious than this way.

Comment: @RuSLDS: Also truncating is not the same a (physically) wiping out. The file's data is still on disk, just only with the permission to be overwritten, whenever this might happen.

Comment: @alk From the point of view of software, the file content is gone. The fact that it might still be there on the storage device is kind of a confusing aside.